# Java: How to Pass multiple Query String in Struts.xml

Tags: java, struts2

i am able to pass only one query string on struts.xml if i am trying to add more queryString code didn't execute. ?
how to resolve it.

`<result name="input" type="redirectAction">../login?status=error</result>` work fine..

but `<result name="input" type="redirectAction">../login?status=error&tab=login</result>` didn't work why?

Comment: what you get in error during the excecution?

Comment: Elaborate on "didn't execute"... What is your action code? Do you have `tab` getters / setters?

Comment: `&amp;tab=login`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-in-xml-documents